# Get value using key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
myDict = {'a': [1, 2, 3, 'cow', {'b': 23}],
         'c': 25
         'd': [4,5,6]}
```

And I want to create a function that would get the values of the keys. This is my code so far:

```
def getValueOf(key, myDict):
for d in myDict:
    if key in d:
        return d[key]
```

This code works only for some dictionaries. I can't seem to wrap my head around another solution.

This is my expected output:

```
getValueOf('b', myDict) ==> 23
getValueOf('d', myDict) ==> [4,5,6]
getValueOf('a', myDict) ==> [1, 2, 3, 'cow', {'b': 23}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why `in`? Use `==`.

Comment: you'll probably need some form of recursion in your `getValueOf` function for both lists and dicts so it works for nested objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an inefficient solution using recursion that goes into lists and dicts:

```py
def find(d, needle):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key in d:
            value = d[key]
            if key == needle:
                return value
            else:
                ret = find(value, needle)
                if ret is not None:
                    return ret
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for value in d:
            ret = find(value, needle)
            if ret is not None:
                return ret
    return None
```

Here's a simple example:

```py
D = {
        "a": 2,
        "b": [1,5,9,2,4, [5, 6, {"g": "pouet"}]],
        "c": {"d": "hello", "e": {"f": "world"}}}

print(find(D, "d"), find(D, "f"))
print(find(D, "g"))
```

which returns:

```
hello world
pouet
```

This can be considered incorrect, since `None` could be a valid value.
To correctly deal with this possibility, consider this instead:

```py
def find(d, needle):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for key in d:
            value = d[key]
            if key == needle:
                return value
            else:
                try:
                    return find(value, needle)
                except RuntimeError:
                    pass
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for value in d:
            try:
                return find(value, needle)
            except RuntimeError:
                pass
    raise RuntimeError
```

Comment: Works like magic. Now I just have to study the lines and understand how it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Eureka I improved the solution in several ways, I hope it's helpful

Comment: Maybe the more clean way to write "for key in d: value = d[key]" is to write "for key, value in d.items():"

Answer (score 1):

```
def getValueOf(key,input_dict):
    if key in input_dict :
        return input_dict[key]
    for k in input_dict :
        current_value = input_dict[k]
        if type(current_value) == list:
            for item in current_value :            
                if type(item)==dict :
                    return getValueOf(key,item)
        elif type(current_value) == dict:
            return getValueOf(key,current_value)
    return None
```

i made this slightly different version, maybe it's easier to understand

Comment: I think the `return get()` lines will interrupt the search too early if the needle isn't in the first dict seen. I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817455/6261350) btw.

Comment: indeed, i didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

Yet another, arguably, simple version.

```py
def get_value(findkey, elements):
    isdict = type(elements) == dict
    found = None
    
    for val in elements:
        if isdict and val == findkey:
            return elements[val]

        val = elements[val] if isdict else val
        if type(val) in [list, dict]:
            found = get_value(findkey, val)

        if found:
            return found
```

Results

```
myDict = {
    "a": 2,
    "b": [1, 5, 9, 2, 4, [5, 6, {"g": "pouet"}]],
    "c": {"d": "hello", "e": {"f": "world"}},
    "h": None,
}


{c: get_value(c, myDict) for c in list('abcdefgh')}
>>>
{'a': 2,
 'b': [1, 5, 9, 2, 4, [5, 6, {'g': 'pouet'}]],
 'c': {'d': 'hello', 'e': {'f': 'world'}},
 'd': 'hello',
 'e': {'f': 'world'},
 'f': 'world',
 'g': 'pouet',
 'h': None}
```